# In web application redirecting user to use latest build

Tags: html, flex3

Say I deploy a new build on server for some web application(flex) and user is still using older version. Is there a way i can notify the user to use the latest version.The problem why im facing this is user never closes the browser

Answer (score 0):

2 ways of doing,

1. Push
2. pull

   1. Push: Use Blazeds to push notifications to the client, use can subscribe to something XYZ notification destination that you implement on the serversid. ofcoz this could be a little tricky as you are turning off the server and turning it back on(all the subscriptions will be gone), blazds channelsets know when the server is turned off, you can write code around this to get resubscribe and get notifications on the client side sent by the server.
   2. Pull: Store the version information in a file, when building, overwrite it with the version that is latest, client will fetch this file every N seconds and compare it with the version it stored in the config.

Comment: Hi zeus .. Thanks for your answer. I understood the pull option. Could you please elaborate on push option?

Comment: let me ask you, if the version of code is changed, do you turn off the machine and turn it on again?

Comment: No.. I'm not restarting my machine just restarting tomcat server.. Thanks

Comment: If you turn off the server everytime the code is changed, the user session does gets destroyed, I think it is better to do a poll rather than Push. Because, Blazeds Push expects you to have the session intact. You might have to devise a way for your client to poll every 1 min or so and find out the new version number.